# How to implement status transitions for an Entity in java?

Tags: java, state, state-machine

I have multiple entities in my application like Users, Accounts, Licenses etc. Each entity has a status associated with it like Active, Ok, Suspended, Unverified, PendingPayment, PendingApproval etc. I want to make sure the entities can move from a predefined status to another like User can only move from Ok to Suspended but not from Unverified to Suspended. What would be the best design pattern to implement this ? I have looked around and mostly find state machines for such problems, but they look too complex for this as I don't want to consider events in the state. All I want to restrict is the transition of states.

As of now, I can think of using a pre-populated 2D array that defines all statuses in each dimension and represents possible transitions. Looking for any better approaches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use in JPA enumerated type. Have a look in the link below.
http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/README.html

```
public enum State {
    STATE1,STATE2(STATE1),STATE3(STATE1,STATE2);

    private State[] previousStates;

    private State(){

    }
    private State(State ...state) {
        this.previousStates =state;
    }

    public State transition(State state) throws Exception {
        for(State tmp: state.previousStates) {
            if (this == tmp) {
                return state;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Illegal state");

    }

}
```

By implementing the method transition within the Enum you will be able to easily set new values for the enum in the JPA you can hide this invocation right into your set method and also it will just throw Exception if the status is incorrect.

Comment: I didn't find anything it that page that explains state transition control.

Comment: I have 12 states for one of the entities. So, that can make the switch case too long. I might still need a 2D array to track the matrix ?

Comment: Actually the switch is not needed I did a mistake to compare the Strings we can use "this" to compare straight with the enum types. But I am sure we can think of something better than 2 dimensional array. Let me think a little bit more.

Comment: I have a better idea. We can keep a back pointer instead of this crazy switch case.  Lets say that you want to move to state "In Progress" we can initialize this ENUM state with back references to all the states that can lead to this "In Progress State" in the example above this is only the OK state so we can have something lie STATE2("OK") back reference. And then the only thing we need to do in the method is to actually check that it is one in the list of the back references. How about that ?

Comment: You like this one better ? I think this is much simpler than a 2D array.

Comment: Have not started implementing this, but sounds like a better way to do what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Alexander's proposal is fine as long as:

- The complexity of state transitions can be managed in a single method
- You don't want to add new states at runtime

For the first bullet point, you might want to consider to implement states as Objects not as enums. Each object/state could have a method that tells you if it was ok to switch to it depending on the current state.

```
interface State {
  boolean isSwitchOk(State currentState);
}

class FinishedState implements State {
   boolean isSwitchOk(State currentState) {
      ...
   }
}
```

You could do it the other way round, as well, i.e. nextState instead of previousState.

In case you need states that can be added at runtime, you could persist them in the DB of your choice. For instance, map the following to your DB (as a JPA example)

```
@Entity
public class State {

   @OneToMany
   private List<State> permittedNextStates;

      public isSwitchOk(State nextState) {
        return permittedNextStates.contains(nextState);
      }
    }
 }
```

In your entity, you could then do

```
public class MyEntity {

   private State currentState;

   public void switchTo(State nextState) {
      if (currentState.isSwitchOk(nextState)) {
         this.currentState = state;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for an **Enum**. This will most essentially ensure

1. Type-safety, so some random status is not set for the entity
2. Singleton final class for all entities to refer to saving much headache.
3. The thing which you require the most,that is, the order of status change which could be implemented by assigning consecutive values to the constructor calls of enum objects/constants such as
   `Active(1), Ok(2), Suspended(3), Unverified(4), PendingPayment(5), PendingApproval(6)`

which can then be kept track for each entity by their own static variables which would be used for incrementing the value and so placing a call to the appropriate constructor and assigning the next status to the entity. This could be done by a `synchronized` method.

Comment: I do not want to rely on the Enum ordering because if I introduce a new status, that might have to be inserted between existing statues, it messes up with the numbers of the existing ones. Also, the statues may not follow pure ordering.

Comment: @TechCrunch I hope you raised this question while having the sheer corporate positives of enum in mind. The best part is that you'd have to do that only once, in a separate file, exclusive for Enum, to be accessed by all entities. Just try to think the possible and probable no. of statuses that you'd have to consider - very low,right? 

*Open the enum file and add the constant with its numbering*

Comment: I have around 10-12 statuses and I have around 5-6 entities. I will find a solution made of all responses and post here. Thank you for taking time to answer.